# RStudio: Move Code to Center of Editor

Tags: rstudio

I am not sure if this is a reasonable expectation or whether there are other IDEs that have this feature, but when I am writing code in the RStudio editor, once I have written a sufficient amount of code, I am basically always editing at the bottom of the screen:

[image]

Is there a way to move the code to the middle of the screen without having to type "Enter" a bunch of times (trailing newlines are code too :-))?

Comment: Although this isn't in the latest RStudio release yet, the preview version has a new option `Allow scroll past end of document`, under the `Display` tab of the editing preferences pane. Feel free to give it a shot https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/ if you're interested.

Comment: @KevinUshey No way! :-) I genuinely thought I would get tumbleweed on this one. That is just perfect -- thank you. If you make an answer, I will give you the fake internet points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep scrolling by clicking an option in the settings:
`Tools -> Global Options -> Code -> Display -> Allow scroll past end of document`

This only affects scripts, and not the console.

*So, uh.. you got some more of that fake internet points?*

Comment: Fake internet points to you -- if you are not too embarrassed to ask for an answer that already has been answered in the comments, you deserve some. :)